# Stash memory issue

Tags: stash, multi-site-manager, memory-limit

So, I'm having a multilanguage one-pager website.

I'm opening with `{exp:stash:cache bundle="onepager_{segment_1}"}` so I can have a bundle for each onepager language.

On localhost, every language (in this case nl, de and fr) are getting their own bundle. 
In my live setup, the first one gets stashed rather quickly, but when I change my url from /nl to /fr for example, it takes ages and I get a memory exhausted error (`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 201326592 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes)`). When I refresh again, the fr bundle gets filled, but the nl bundle is gone.

Some important things to know, that might be of importance here.
This website is using multi-site manager. Also, the onepager is using switchee. If segment_2 is empty, it has `{stash:embed:layouts:one_pager}`, otherwise it has `{stash:embed:layouts:detail}`. If it's not, it shows a detail-page of an event. 
The reason I'm doing it this way, instead of having a different page-type, is multi-language stuff. Every detail-entry is having all fields for every language, rather then splitting it up. But since they're not in structure because of this (as I can not add a listing to a master page) I'm doing it like this.

So, the question is, am I doing something wrong here, or is my server not able to handle this?

Thanks!

EDIT: I changed my approach a bit. I made another page-type specifically for detail-entries and made a hidden page for it. This way, I made sure I only had logic for my onepage in my onepager page-type. Yet, the issue remains.

Comment: Is session_save_path critical for stash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well okay.
This seemed to be the killer here: `{stash:embed file_name="snippets:document:html_footer_includes"}` rather than `{stash:embed name="snippets:document:html_footer_includes"}`.

So it's fixed, but I'd be good to know the difference between file_name and name in this context :) And why it does work local, and exhausts my memory in production.